# How to stop a play and return right values in TPL?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

In my TPL application, I want to play a text to speech by a method `PlayTTS(string text)` to do it.

```
public static CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
public static CancellationToken cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
```

Then in the consumer method.

```
async Task Consumer()
    {
        try
        {
            var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50,
                CancellationToken = cToken
            };
            var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<AppointmentReminder>(
            remainder =>
            {
               if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                  return;
                Dictionary<string, string> dict = new OutboundDial(ts).RunScript(remainder, cToken);
                // update UI by the returned dictionary
            },
            executionDataflowBlockOptions);

            m_bufferBlock.LinkTo(
            consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
            await consumerBlock.Completion;
        }
```

I have a button event to cancel the process(WPF).

```
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

You see there is `cToken.IsCancellationRequested` in the `ActionBlock`, however it did not help to stop the process in the method `OutboundDial(ts).RunScript(remainder, cToken);` although I passed into the cancellation token.

Now let's look at the method `RunScript`.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> RunScript(AppointmentReminder callData, CancellationToken cToken)
    {
        try
        {
             m_ChannelResource = m_TelephonyServer.GetChannel() as SipChannel;
             m_VoiceResource = m_ChannelResource.VoiceResource;
             // Many logging
             // Dial out

            MakeTest(callData, cToken);
        }
        catch
         {throw;}
        finally
        {
            // destroy m_ChannelResource and m_VoiceResource
         }
        return dict;
    }
```

The key point is the method `MakeTest`, inside it we have `PlayTTS`;

```
public void MakeTest(AppointmentReminder callData, CancellationToken cToken)
{
    try
    {
        if (!cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            m_VoiceResource.PlayTTS(callData.Text);  
        }
        else
        {
            cToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            m_VoiceResource.Stop(); // Stops any current activity on m_VoiceResource.
            dict["ConnectedTime"] = " no connection";
            dict["DialingResult"] = " cancellation";
        }
```

My current code didn't reach `m_VoiceResource.Stop()` part when I click the cancel button. 
So my question is when `cTokenSource.Cancel();`, how to let code run at:

```
m_VoiceResource.Stop(); // Stops any current activity on m_VoiceResource.
dict["ConnectedTime"] = " no connection";
dict["DialingResult"] = " cancellation";
```

**EDIT: 1:10pm Oct 31 2014**

Based on the comment by Servy, I used `cToken.Register(() => m_VoiceResource.Stop());`

I created a similar demo at [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=03A8BB9EAEEFF1DB&id=3A8BB9EAEEFF1DB!4159).

Comment: The m_VoiceResponse.Stop() shouldn't ever execute because you are throwing an exception on the previous line if cancel was requested

Comment: @BobVale, please play my demo from OneDrive, you will find out the issue. It just used `Console.WriteLine()`.(No exception at all).

Comment: `cToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` will raise an exceptin

Comment: @BobVale, I removed that line but same thing.  If you could like to look at my clean source code on https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=03A8BB9EAEEFF1DB&id=3A8BB9EAEEFF1DB!4159, you would understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution under the help from a Microsoft MVP. 
Servy's solution was beautiful but with flaw.

```
cToken.Register(() => m_VoiceResource.Stop());
```

The registration should be placed before start playing rather than after it.

**EDIT:** Nov 10 2014 8:09 am

A better one:

```
 cToken.Register(() => m_VoiceResource.Stop());
 return;
```

Comment: If you register the callback before you start playing then it can be called, stopping the player before it has been started, then starting it after it can no longer be stopped.

Comment: @Servy,Then I would like pass two tokens, one is before, the other is after playing. Can I?

Comment: There's no *reason* to do that.  If the token is actually cancelled before you start, then the one registering before won't do anything.  If the cancellation happens after it starts then they both do the same thing.  There is simply no reason to register the callback before starting the player at all.

Comment: @Servy, the phenomenon you said did exist. However, if the registration is after playing. It **can't** stop playing unless put it before it. For example, only there is one item in the queue. It just kept playing.

Comment: If you can never stop the playing once it has started then there's no purpose in registering the call back *at all*.  It doesn't matter whether you do it before or after, if there is no way to stop the player once it starts, you'll never do any better than the `if (!cToken.IsCancellationRequested)` check you already have before you start playing.

Comment: @Servy, but I think the register's position might matter. Please see the [sample answer.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e346b94-3a34-45fc-89ae-ddc242661e4c/cancellationtokensource-is-not-working?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: You don't *want* the callback to run before this other code in the event that the cancellation token is already cancelled.  The OP does want it in that case.  In your case if the callback actually fires before the other code in question then your program won't work.  In the other example his program *requires* that reversed order.

Answer (score 5):

You're cancelling the token after you have already checked if the token is canceled and begun playing.  You are never going back and performing that condition again to stop.

What you need to do is simply register a callback to the token's cancellation that stops the player:

```
cToken.Register(() => m_VoiceResource.Stop());
```

Simply add that registration immediately after you start playing.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. The code did reach at `Stop`, but is was after playing the entire text. And it seemed waiting a little time. By stepping into the code, say if we had three items in the queue, I found `PlayTTS` was executed three times and then `m_VoiceResource.Stop()` three times as well.

Comment: @Love Then it sounds like your problem is with whatever tool you're using (a tool that you have provided no information about, I might add).  You'll need to look into why it's not stopping its work when you call `Stop`.

Comment: Servy. I meant the callback could not been executed immediately after clicking the cancel button. It is supposed to jump into it by MSDN.

Comment: I don't know but perhaps not. I can play the windows using mouse when PlayTTS.(WPF app) I stepped into button click event, it did reached there. The callback is not in the windows class, it is in my custom class.(see my code)

Comment: Guys, trust me. I created a demo at https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=03A8BB9EAEEFF1DB&id=3A8BB9EAEEFF1DB!4159. The file name is "CancellationTokenIsNotWorking.zip". The project original was a wpf project, I changed the project's property as console, so it can output the results on the screen. All you need to do is click the start button then click cancel button, but it could not stop it on the screen.